# Call Method From interface in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, interface

I'm trying to create a method called makeDogsBark() in my DogOwner class which should execute the bark() method of all the dogs the current DogOwner has.

When I tried to call the method I got the follow error.
*DogOwner.java:21: error: Dog is abstract; cannot be instantiated*

**This is my interface Dog.java:**

```
public interface Dog {
String getName();
String getBreed();
void bark();
}
```

**This is my 1st class Doggo.java:**

```
public class Doggo implements Dog {
    private String name;

    public Doggo(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBreed() {
        return "doggo";
    }

    @Override
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("The doggo " + name + " made a noise: Woof!, it said.");
    }
}
```

**This is my 2nd class Pupper.java:**

```
public class Pupper implements Dog {
    private String name;

    public Pupper(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBreed() {
        return "pupper";
    }

    @Override
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("The pupper " + name + " made a noise: Bark! Bark! Bark!, it said.");
    }
}
```

**This is my third class DogOwner.java:**

```
public class DogOwner {

private String name;
private ArrayList<Dog> dogsOwned;

public DogOwner(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public void adoptDog(Dog newDog){
    if(!this.dogsOwned.contains(dogsOwned)){
        this.dogsOwned.add(newDog);
    }

}

public void makeDogsBark(){
    System.out.println("The person " + name + " made all his/hers dogs bark.");
    Dog dog = new Dog();
    dog.bark();
}
}
```

Comment: May i know where do you call these methods? kindly post what error you received

Comment: "I attemtped to do it but it's not working" - "it's not working" is *never* enough information. Does it compile but throw an exception? Does it not compile? Does it compile and then run without exceptions, but not give the expected result? What *is* the expected result? Please provide a [mcve] with a clear statement of expected vs actual behaviour.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks edited my original post now with the error.

Comment: You can't create object to interface, Make instance to a class and call the methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mandatory (for compilation)

An interface cannot be instantiated:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();  // <-- This cannot possibly compile
```

You must choose between:

```
Dog dog = new Doggo("good boy");
```

and

```
Dog dog = new Pupper("good boy");
```

Then the method to get every dog to bark should loop on the list:

```
public void makeDogsBark() {
    this.dogsOwned.forEach(Dog::bark);
}
```

Or the Java 7- version:

```
public void makeDogsBark() {
    for (Dog dog : this.dogsOwned) {
        dog.bark();
    }
}
```

---

### Optional (for code quality)

(*optional*) The property dogsOwned should also be a `List`:

```
private List<Dog> dogsOwned;
```

And be instantiated in the constructor:

```
public DogOwner(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dogsOwned = new ArrayList<>();  // new ArrayList<Dog>() Java 7-
}
```

(*optional*) Also, if you want your Dog collection to be unique, use a Set instead of a list.

```
private Set<Dog> dogsOwned;

public DogOwner(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dogsOwned = new HashSet<>();  // new HashSet<Dog>() Java 7-
}
```

So that you can just:

```
public void adoptDog(Dog newDog) {
    this.dogsOwned.add(newDog);  // Won't add anything that already exists in the Set
}
```

The thing is, that will compare the object reference which is not always ideal.
In order to avoid that kind of comparison, you can override the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods to compare the objects the way **you** want. Check for "implement equals and hashcode" on your favorite search engine.

Comment: Hm getting the following error then: error: constructor Doggo in class Doggo cannot be applied to given types;
        Dog dog = new Doggo();

Comment: You must **never** write `new Dog()` anywhere in your code. Change all occurrences of that with one of the two implementations of Dog.

Comment: The constructor requires you to give it a name. So use new `new Doggo("good boy")`. That, or write another contructor for the Doggo class that doesn't take any argument.

Comment: Should also mention that `Dog` implementations need to implement proper `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods

Comment: Thanks Adrien! Solved my problem :-)

We are only allowed to use ArrayList unfortunately.

Ran into a new problem though, apparently you are supposed to be able to create 2 DogOwners, this was the error I was getting:
http://d.pr/i/KXGktF
I can't see why that is problem though? Or should I create a new instance variable?

Comment: Even with the `contains` approach with a `List`, you should implement your own `.equals` and `.hashcode` so that contains returns the correct value. I can't click on your link (I'm behind work proxy), if you have another problem and **can't find a solution on SO**, submit another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void makeDogsBark(){
    dogsOwned.forEach(it -> it.bark());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an interface.

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
```

This is a false line of code.

Instead of this, you can iterate through the **dogsOwned** list and make each dog bark instead.

```
for(Dog dog : dogsOwned){
        dog.bark();   
}
```

You can also skip the loop in Java 8 by using this.

```
dogsOwned.forEach(dog->dog.bark());
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: And if you gave an example how to do it right, it would be a proper answer!